# c# Leer rango de excel mediante el nombre de una tabla

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

El siguiente código lee de un rango de excel, es decir le envía la query al OleDbDataAdapter y le devuelve el DataTable.

```
    public static System.Data.DataTable ReadExcelRangeToDataTable(string file_path, string sheet_name, string range)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
        OleDbConnection SQLConn = new OleDbConnection(GetExcelConnectionString(file_path));
        SQLConn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter SQLAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheet_name + "$" + range + "]";
        sql += " WHERE LEN(F1) > 0";
        OleDbCommand selectCMD = new OleDbCommand(sql, SQLConn);
        SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCMD;
        SQLAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        SQLConn.Close();
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Lo que necesitaría es poder hacer la misma query, pero accediendo por nombre de tabla (tblUsuarios).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has probado sin poner el nombre de la hoja? Algo así `SELECT * FROM [" + range + "]"`

Comment: Buenas @RogerTorné, lo probé y me dice: 
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'tblUsuarios'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'tblUsuarios' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.